# How $L_\infty$-norm can be represented by a set of inequality?

Tags: normed-spaces, convex-optimization, convex-hulls

I am studying Boyd's convex optimization book and came across the following two concepts, which I couldn't explain to myself why. It was mentioned in the book that the set $C$ with $L_\infty$-norm:

$C = \{x\ |\ \|x_i\|\le 1,\ i = 1, \cdots, n\}$

can be described in the form with $2n$ linear inequalities $±e_i^Tx\le 1$,
Where $e_i$ is the *i*th unit vector. Could someone elaborate on this?

The book continues and claims that at least $2^n$ points are needed to describe it in the convex hull form of $\{\theta_1v_1 + · · · + \theta_kv_k\ |\ \theta_1 + · · · + \theta_m = 1, \theta_i\ge 0,\ i = 1, \cdots , k\}$:

$C = \boldsymbol{\rm conv}\{v_1, \cdots, v_{2^n}\}$

where $v_1, \cdots, v_{2^n}$ are the $2^n$ vectors all of whose components are 1 or −1. Also, I could not figure out why this is a true statement. I would appreciate any hint so I can understand these two points.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $ f \left( x \right) $ is a convex function and one wants to solve the following:

$$\begin{alignat*}{3}
\arg \min_{x} & \quad & f \left( x \right) \\
\text{subject to} & \quad & \left\| x \right\|_{\infty} \leq 1
\end{alignat*}$$

What does it means $ \left\| x \right\|_{\infty} \leq 1 $?

Well, by the definition of the $ {L}_{\infty} $ norm it means:

$$ \max_{i} \left| {x}_{i} \right| \leq 1 $$

If the maximum is smaller than 1 we could replace it by having all elements less than 1:

$$ \max_{i} \left| {x}_{i} \right| \leq 1 \Leftrightarrow \forall i \, \left| {x}_{i} \right| \leq 1 $$

Now, using the property of the Absolute Function $ \left| \cdot \right| $:

$$ \max_{i} \left| {x}_{i} \right| \leq 1 \Leftrightarrow \forall i \, \left| {x}_{i} \right| \leq 1 \Leftrightarrow \forall i \, -1 \leq {x}_{i} \leq 1 $$

Now, if $ x \in \mathbb{R}^{n} $ the last term is basically 2 $ 2 n $ simple equations.

Which means our convex problem can be reformulated as:

$$\begin{alignat*}{3}
\arg \min_{x} & \quad & f \left( x \right) & \quad \\
\text{subject to} & \quad & {x}_{i} \leq 1 &  \quad \forall i \\
 & \quad & -{x}_{i} \leq 1 &  \quad \forall i
\end{alignat*}$$